# Python, Using repeated field in API

Tags: python-2.7, api, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an API presented as follow. If the API is called with only one value in params (which is a repeated field), everything work as intended. But if params holds multiple values, then I get error : No endpoint found for path.

```
 1    INPUT = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
 2               params = messages.IntegerField(1, repeated = True, variant = messages.Variant.INT32))
 3
 4    @endpoints.method(INPUT, 
 5                      response_type.CustomResponse,
 6                      path = 'foo/{params}', 
 7                      http_method = 'POST',
 8                      name = 'foo')
 9    def foo(self, request):
10        #foo body is irrelevent
11        return response
```

How can I fix this. Something like : path = 'foo/{params[]}', ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have a variable number of arguments?Or explicitly know the arguments that will be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'params' is expected as part of the query string and not the path, you can just omit it from the path eg:

```
path = 'foo'
```

or

```
path = 'myApi/foo'
```

The [example given in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#using_resourcecontainer_for_path_or_querystring_arguments) uses a ResourceContainer for a single non-repeated path argument. Given the nature of repeated properties it doesn't look like you can use them as path arguments, only query string arguments. A repeated field in a query string would look like this (easily to deal with):

```
POST http://app.appspot.com/_ah/api/myApi/v1/foo?param=bar&param=baz ...
```

But a repeated field in a path argument would look like this (not so much):

```
POST http://app.appspot.com/_ah/api/myApi/v1/foo/bar/baz....
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Despite the fact that now param is no longer a required field and the URL has a different syntax, is there any other side effect of this change ?

Comment: There should be none other than what was mentioned above.